# Sending App to another phone with the current db of app

Tags: database, sqlite, send

I have an application wherein I create a SQLite database for storing user information. So I need to have a option, so that a person can send app to other person WITH the db. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about a web application which stores data using sqlite in the user's browser on their phone.

There would be no way to take the data from one user's (user1) sqlite database and send it directly to another user (user2). However, you could find a way to transfer the contents of the database to a server application, then make those contents available to the other user.

You can use a number of methods to send the data from user1 to the server. You could use an Ajax POST to the server (if the server is on the same domain), build a form to POST the data, etc.

Sending user2 the data would be straight forward. Pick a format to deliver the data in (JSON probably), send the data from the server to user2, and have a script in user2's browser read the data and INSERT it into their local sqlite storage.